# using a Constructor statement (constructor?)

Tags: constructor

I'm new to Java, so I'm sure this is an easy question (my head is spinning from studying all day long). Here's the code I'm studying and can't remember/figure out what this line of code is doing:

```
public Temperature(String type, double degrees) { 
if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
```

Is this considered a constructor? What are the two parameters "String type, double degrees" doing? tia.

Here's the code from the top down:

```
public class Temperature { 
private double degreesFahrenheit; // Fahrenheit temperature
private double degreesCelsius; // Celsius temperature 
private double degreesKelvin; // Kelvin temperature

/** * This constructor for Temperature sets the temperature 
*   values to the value from degrees, based on the type * 
* @param type temperature scale to use 
* @param degrees degrees Fahrenheit 
*/ 

public Temperature(String type, double degrees) { 
if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
setDegreesCelsius(degrees); 
else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("F")) setDegreesFahrenheit(degrees);
else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("K")) setDegreesKelvin(degrees);
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! This:

```
public Temperature(String type, double degrees){
    ...
}
```

is a constructor.
Basically what it does when called is to create a new Temperature object and set some fields in the class by:

**1)** Check if the arguement `type` is `C` or `c`, `F` or `f`, `K` or `k` and 
**2)** appropriatelly call the methods:
 `setDegreesCelsius(degrees);` , `setDegreesFahrenheit(degrees);` and `setDegreesKelvin(degrees);` respectivelly.

You haven't posted the code for those methods but its most likely that:

if the input is `C` you assign `degreesCelsius;` the value of the `degree` arguement of your constructor.

Similarly if `F` to the `degreesFahrenheit;` and if `K`to the `degreesKelvin;`

The definition of these methods probably looks like this:

```
setDegreesCelsius(double degrees){
    this.degreesCelsius = degrees;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Update after your comment:**

`public Temperature(String type, double degrees)` that the constructor only accepts 2 arguements. a `String` and a `double`. There are there so that you can create a `Temperature` instance and also set the values of some fiels.

For example this code :

`Temperate x = new Temperature("C", 35);` means that `x` is a `Temperature` object and counts in the Celcious scale, and the current temperature is 35.

Hope this makes more sense

Comment: Helpful, but still struggling. What/why is "String type, double degrees" doing there? I haven't run across that before (I don't think).

Comment: Yes, makes more sense. Thank you very much.