# Actual and formal argument lists differ in length Java

Tags: java

I keep getting that constructor largeCylinder = new Cylinder(label, height, radius); differs from the parameters set in my class.

The Main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CylinderApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   ////////////////////////////////////////
      String label;
      double radius, height;
      Scanner scanz = new Scanner(System.in);
   ///////////////////////////////////////
      Cylinder largeCylinder;
   ///////////////////////////////////////
      System.out.println("Enter label, radius, and height for a cylinder.");
      System.out.print("label: ");
      label = scanz.nextLine();
      System.out.print("radius: ");
      radius = Double.parseDouble(scanz.nextLine());
      System.out.print("height: ");
      height = Double.parseDouble(scanz.nextLine());
   /////////////////////////////////
     largeCylinder = new Cylinder(label, height, radius);
     System.out.println(largeCylinder);
   }
}
```

The class Cylinder:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
/* amazing.
*/
public class Cylinder {
/* amazing.
*/
   private String label;
   private double height; /* height of cylinder. */
   private double radius; /* radius of cylinder. */
   public static final double PI = Math.PI; /*constant Pi. */
   private double diameter;
   private double circumference;
   private double area; 
   private double volume;
   private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0##");

////////////////////////////////////////
 public boolean setLabel(String labelIn){
 if (label == null)
      {
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         label = labelIn;
         label = label.trim();
         return true;
      }
   }
 public String getLabel() {
      return label;
   }
   public void setHeight(double heightIn) {
      height = heightIn;
   }
   public double getHeight() {
      return height;
   }
   public void setRadius(double radiusIn) {
      radius = radiusIn;
   }
   public double getRadius() {
      return radius;
   }
   public double diameter() {
      return radius * 2;
   }
   public double circumference() {
      return 2 * PI * getRadius();
   }
   public double area() {
      return ((2 * PI * radius * height) + (2 * PI * Math.pow(radius, 2))); 
   }
   public double volume() {
      return PI * Math.pow(radius, 2) * height;
   }


   /////////////////////////////////////

   /////////////////////////////////////
   public String toString() {
      return "\n" + "\"" + getLabel() + "\"" + " is a cylinder with radius = " 
         + df.format(getRadius()) + " units and height = " 
         + df.format(getHeight()) + ",\n" 
         + " which as a diameter = "
         + df.format(diameter()) + " units, circumference = " 
         + df.format(circumference()) + " units,\n"
         + " area = " + df.format(area()) + " square units, and volume = " 
         + df.format(volume())
         + " cubic units."; 
   }
}
```

I dont understand why it says the parameters do not match when label, radius, and height are all set in the Cylinder.class

Comment: The Cylinder class doesn't seem to have a constructor with signature (label, height, radius)

Comment: if I set in the main class new Cylinder(label) and then proceed to Cylinder.setHeight(height); and Cylinder.setRadius(radius); it gives me the same error

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a constructor with signature (String) either. Could you perhaps look at a tutorial and find out what a constructor is?

Comment: Or you could look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775088/using-a-constructor-statement-constructor

Answer (score 2):

When you call this line in your main class:

```
largeCylinder = new Cylinder(label, height, radius);
```

you get an error bcz there is no constructor in your Cynlinder class that does this. In fact, you have NO constructors at all in your cynlinder class.

Put this into your Cylinder class and try again:

```
public Cylinder(String constructLabel, double constructHeight, double constructRadius) {
    // required constructor class
    label = constructLabel;
    height = constructHeight;
    radius = constructRadius;
}
```

Now create the object and do this to calculate the cylinder:

```
System.out.println(largeCylinder);
```

You other option is to just say:

```
largeCylinder = new Cylinder();
largeCylinder.setLabel(label);
largeCylinder.setRadius(radius);
largeCylinder.setHeight(height);
System.out.println(largeCylinder);
```

Comment: OP doesn't need the `.toString()` invocation inside `println()`. It's implicitly invoked. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-

Comment: even when I put largeCylinder = new Cylinder();
largeCylinder.setLabel(label);
largeCylinder.setRadius(radius);
largeCylinder.setHeight(height);
System.out.println(largeCylinder);  the program works, however, the boolean for setLabel always comes out null

Comment: It is not possible to return null for a boolean method. Your setLabel method just returns true/false. The GETLABEL method, though, will return a String which can be null. Show your code where you are getting the null return for a boolean method.